# .htaccess add multiple xdebug.remote_host

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I am using NetBeans to remote debug a PHP application.  Currently I have an entry in the .htaccess file on the remote directory to allow access to a single IP.  I frequently switch between wired and wireless connections, so I would like to add multiple IPs.  Is this possible, if so how?

Currently my .htaccess entry looks something like this.

```
php_value xdebug.remote_host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can just add another entry on the .htaccess file.

```
php_value   xdebug.remote_host   "localhost"  
php_value   xdebug.remote_host   "128.123.1.3"
```

Comment: I guess you can't do that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the hostname of the computer.

On a Mac:

1. System Preferences.
2. Under Internet & Wireless, click Sharing.
3. The hostname should be the Computer Name (Ex. VPC12354).

On a PC:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. type the following and hit enter.

   > ipconfig/all
3. Your Host Name will be listed.